# Convert exponential to number in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large amount of card tokens (16 digits) uploaded from xml file to sql-server. The problem is I see them as expression, sample below:

```
3.3733E+15
3.3737E+15
3.3737E+15
3.3737E+15
3.37391E+15
3.37391E+15
3.37398E+15
3.37453E+15
3.37468E+15
3.37468E+15
3.3747E+15
3.37486E+15
3.37486E+15
3.37567E+15
3.3759E+15
3.3759E+15
```

Any suggestion to change them to a 16 digit number? I have tried to change the data type, but got error`"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3.37201E+15' to data type int"`

Thanks for help!

Edit:

@X.L.Ant see my code below. I create this table from another one, which is just purely inserted from xml file. Is this may cause an error because some rows are empty in column TOKEN?

```
 CREATE TABLE MULTICURRENCY_CHECK
    (
    TOKEN varchar(255)
    )
    /*Merges all card tokens into 1 column, as in xml they are spread across different columns*/                                
    INSERT INTO MULTICURRENCY_CHECK
    (
    TOKEN
    )
    SELECT no FROM gpstransactionsnew2
        UNION ALL
    SELECT no19 FROM gpstransactionsnew2
        UNION ALL
    SELECT no68 FROM gpstransactionsnew2
        UNION ALL
    SELECT no93 FROM gpstransactionsnew2
        UNION ALL
    SELECT no107 FROM gpstransactionsnew2
        UNION ALL
    SELECT no121 FROM gpstransactionsnew2

    SELECT REPLACE(TOKEN, 'OW1', ' ')
    FROM MULTICURRENCY_CHECK

    /*Converts exponential expression to number*/
    SELECT CONVERT(numeric(16,0), CAST(TOKEN AS FLOAT))
    FROM MULTICURRENCY_CHECK
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try to cast your string to float before converting it :

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric(16,0), CAST(TOKEN AS FLOAT))
FROM MULTICURRENCY_CHECK
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a484f/1).

I don't know what's the format of those numbers in your XML source, but with the data you provide, you'll end up with 33733 for instance followed by a bunch of zeroes. If you have a bigger precision in your XML, maybe you should tweak your importing settings to keep this precision instead of trying to deal with that in the DB.

**EDIT:**

Try testing your strings with `ISNUMERIC` to avoid the casting errors you're getting. Adding a raw output of your column will allow you to check which value fails to convert (i.e. converts to 0).

```
SELECT TOKEN, 
       CONVERT(NUMERIC(16, 0), CAST(CASE 
                                      WHEN ISNUMERIC(TOKEN) = 1
                                      THEN TOKEN 
                                      ELSE 0 
                                    END AS FLOAT)) 
FROM   MULTICURRENCY_CHECK
```

Comment: I know this, but it will convert just 1 number right? I want to convert all (more then 20k rows)

Comment: @Lukas what do you mean by `it will convert just 1 number`...it think this should work

Comment: Got error: Error 8114: Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: Weird, it's working on my machine (SQL Server 2008 R2), and on [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a484f/1) with 2014. What is the exact content of a field ?

Comment: What do you mean by exact content? Please see my answer below with full code.

Comment: I edited my answer to allow you to track down the faulty values.

Comment: Okay I've run it on one of the columns from original table and it is working. Strange it is not working after I merge those columns. Maybe there are some other text string combined with numbers than the one I've removed. And you are right, it gives me back number +10 zeros, so I assume the only way is to change settings while uploading the file?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how you import it, but try to force this field as string to avoid to lose precision by formatting numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**For SQL Server 2012+, use [TRY_CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql).**

The use of ISNUMERIC() in xlecoustillier's edited answer does not protect against conversion failures.

Given the following scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE test(a varchar(100));

insert into test values ('3.3733E+15'),
('3.3737E+15'),
('3.37391E+30'), --fails conversion. included to demonstrate the nature of TRY_CONVERT().
('3.37398E+15'),
('3.37453E+15'),
('3.37468E+15'),
('3.3747E+15'),
('3.37486E+15'),
('3.37567E+15'),
('3.3759E+15');

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(numeric(16,0), CAST(a AS FLOAT))
FROM test
```

Results in only valid converted values:

```
---------------------------------------
3373300000000000
NULL
3373910000000000
3373980000000000
3374530000000000
3374680000000000
3374700000000000
3374860000000000
3375670000000000
3375900000000000
```

However:

```
SELECT a, 
       CONVERT(NUMERIC(16, 0), CAST(CASE 
                                      WHEN ISNUMERIC(a) = 1
                                      THEN a 
                                      ELSE 0 
                                    END AS FLOAT)) 
FROM   test
```

Fails with:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3.3733E+15' to
> data type int.

The issue is that all values in the 'a' column return 1 when passed to the ISNUMERIC() function.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(a) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as IsValueNumeric
FROM test
```

[Try it on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/564a13/3) and/or compare with [xlecoustillier's sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a484f/1)

Answer (score -6):

```
SELECT colmn_name || '' FROM table_name
```

This should work.