# Query to convert exponential number to float in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, exponential

I am using

```
SELECT CAST('5E-05' AS float)
```

result = 0.00005

and it is not working. Help.

[https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=5E-05+to+decimal](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=5E-05%20to%20decimal)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149910/convert-exponential-to-number-in-sql

Comment: What is the output? what is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide correct output for this so that we test and throw few more sample data.

Try this,

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,8), CAST('5E-05' AS FLOAT))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, actually what i got was 0 , but your query got me into 0.00005. thanks again