# Converting scientific notation to decimal in SQL Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I'm working with Amazon Athena and there are several columns that come out as scientific notation and I need it to come out as either an integer or a decimal. I've tried doing the answer from this: [Convert exponential to number in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149910/convert-exponential-to-number-in-sql)

However, that doesn't work with SQL Presto, and this one doesn't work because I need it for multiple numbers, not just one: [Query to convert exponential number to float in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914381/query-to-convert-exponential-number-to-float-in-sql-server)

Comment: "several columns that come out as scientific notation" -- do you mean they are of type `double` or `real`?

Comment: they come out like this which is E notation I believe: 9.46725E+11

Answer (score 7):

It should work if you cast the column to decimal.

```
SELECT CAST(doubleColumn AS decimal(22,2)) from my_table
```

There's no way to convert it globally.