# Convert Excel Exponential Format back to its text in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

First off I am have a constraint the my solution must work from **SQL Server 2008 R2**

The problem that I'm trying to solve is that Excel converts the text value '002E9' to 2.00E+09.  The task is to pass the original value ***'002E9'*** as **text** into a CSV file.

I have been passed a SSIS solution by a developer that has a the conversion as a SQL function.  They have used

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(2.00E+09 AS FLOAT),'0E0');
```

This is fine in 2012 and above but does not work in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Is there a simple alternative? I'm happy to abandon SQL for a SSIS script if that's the best advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert exponential to number in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149910/convert-exponential-to-number-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FORMAT` doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008; but it's use is best avoided any way; it's an awfully slow function.

You can use `CONVERT` and the style `0` though:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST(2.00E+09 AS float),0),'+','');
```

This won't, however, give exactly the same format, and would return `'2e009'`. Based on  the fact that you use the value `'0E0'` for the `FORMAT` function though (which would return `'2E9'` for your example value), I assume this is permissible.

Comment: Nothing change and giving the same output as in exponential input.

Comment: What do you mean, nothing changed?

Comment: Output of your query is - 2e009. It should be in the number back after conversion.

Comment: Yes, that's what the answer says, @SurajKumar *"and would return `'2e009'`"*; which is what the OP is after; *"The task is to pass the original value '002E9' as text into a CSV file."*

Comment: got it, I was thinking the output should be in the normal number like 200000..

Comment: OK so not quite what I'm after, the OP states  The task is to pass the original value **'002E9'** as text into a CSV file.
However its a start I'll see if that gets me closer that I currently am.
Thanks

Comment: I do cover that in my answer, @StephenConnell . *"This won't, however, give exactly the same format, and would return `'2e009'`. Based on  the fact that you use the value `'0E0'` for the `FORMAT` function though (which would return `'2E9'` for your example value), I assume this is permissible."*. So even the solution you have on 2012+ using `FORMAT` doesn't return the value you say you're after (but you say it works).

Comment: Thanks this gave me enough to complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the post Larnu made I arrived at this  (*note the REPLICATE function for getting the correct format from the stripped down string*):

```
DECLARE @INPUTS AS table 
(input_val varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @INPUTS
VALUES
('00923'),('00234'),('00568'),('00123'),('2.00E+09' ),('2.00E+34' ),('00RT1'),('001TL')

SELECT input_val 
,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(input_val,'+',''),'0',''),'.','') paired_value
,REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(input_val,'+',''),'0',''),'.','')))
    +REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(input_val,'+',''),'0',''),'.','')+';' Converted_value
FROM @INPUTS
```

The results:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+
| input_val | paired_value | Converted_value |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+
| 00923     | 923          | 00923;          |
| 00234     | 234          | 00234;          |
| 00568     | 568          | 00568;          |
| 00123     | 123          | 00123;          |
| 2.00E+09  | 2E9          | 002E9;          |
| 2.00E+34  | 2E34         | 02E34;          |
| 00RT1     | RT1          | 00RT1;          |
| 001TL     | 1TL          | 001TL;          |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Confirms the approach.
Thanks Larnu.